# How to implement a part of histogram equalization in matlab without using for loops and influencing speed and performance

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, time, histogram

Suppose that I have these Three variables in matlab  [Variables](http://www.4shared.com/rar/xUDqy8up/variables.html)
I want to extract diverse values in NewGrayLevels and sum rows of OldHistogram that are in the same rows as one diverse value is.
For example you see in NewGrayLevels that the six first rows are equal to zero. It means that 0 in the NewGrayLevels has taken its value from (0 1 2 3 4 5) of OldGrayLevels. So the corresponding rows in OldHistogram should be summed.
So 0+2+12+38+113+163=328 would be the frequency of the gray level 0 in the equalized histogram and so on.
Those who are familiar with image processing know that it's part of the histogram equalization algorithm.
Note that I don't want to use built-in function "histeq" available in image processing toolbox and I want to implement it myself.
I know how to write the algorithm with for loops. I'm seeking if there is a faster way without using for loops.
The code using for loops:

```
   for k=0:255
       Condition = NewGrayLevels==k;
       ConditionMultiplied = Condition.*OldHistogram;
       NewHistogram(k+1,1) = sum(ConditionMultiplied);
   end
```

I'm afraid if this code gets slow for high resolution big images.Because the variables that I have uploaded are for a small image downloaded from the internet but my code may be used for sattellite images.

Comment: Can you show us your algorithm using the for loop to guide an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I understood that there's no need to write the code that @Hugh Nolan suggested. See the explanation here:

```
%The green lines are because after writing the code, I understood that  
%there's no need to calculate the equalized histogram in  
%"HistogramEqualization" function and after gaining the equalized image  
%matrix you can pass it to the "ExtractHistogram" function  
% (which there's no loops in it) to acquire the  
%equalized histogram.    
%But I didn't delete those lines of code because I had tried a lot to  
%understand the algorithm and write them.
```

For more information and studying the code, please see [my next question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303335/apply-new-equalized-histogram-on-the-image-matrix-in-matlab/17307756#17307756)

Answer (score 2):

I know you say you don't want to use histeq, but it might be worth your time to look at the MATLAB source file to see how the developers wrote it and copy the parts of their code that you would like to implement. Just do edit('histeq') or edit('histeq.m'), I forget which.

Usually the MATLAB code is vectorized where possible and runs pretty quick. This could save you from having to reinvent the entire wheel, just the parts you want to change.

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for a way how to see matlab's implementation for a special function.

Comment: Yeah, the rule of thumb with MATLAB is if it is a compiled mfile, you can't see the code (its proprietary). Many of the basic MATLAB operations are compiled for speed. You will still be able to say edit('filename') but there won't be any actual code there, just a bunch of commented out doc. Just an extra FYI :)

Comment: Dear @Shaun314 when I type edit('conv2'),edit('fft') and edit('fftn'),I just see the documentation of the m-files (I mean comments that are written in it) not the implementation.Why does it happen?

Comment: The reason is that these are all built in functions and everything I wrote in my comment above is your answer to your new comment. You can't see the MATLAB code because there is none! It is written in C, not MATLAB, and it is MATLAB's "secret" code. It sounds like you could have made your initial question much clearer.

Comment: ok @Shaun314 functions like 'fft2' that we have access to their code are built-in functions developed in matlab with the use of other basic built-in functions like 'fft' and 'fftn' that are developed using C-family languages and converted to matlab right?    So we have access to the code of some built-in functions in matlab like fft2 but not basic built-ins like fft,fftn,conv2 and etc right?   well maybe you are right, but first of all it was not my question, I just got more curious with your answer,thanks for your attention

Answer (score 2):

I can't think a way to implement this without a for loop somewhere, but one optimisation you could make would be using indexing instead of multiplication:

```
for k=0:255
    Condition = NewGrayLevels==k; % These act as logical indices to OldHistogram
    NewHistogram(k+1,1) = sum(OldHistogram(Condition)); % Removes a vector multiplication,   some additions, and an index-to-double conversion
end
```

Edit:

On rereading your initial post, I think that the way to do this without a for loop is to use accumarray (I find this a difficult function to understand, so read the documentation and search online and on here for examples to do so):

```
NewHistogram = accumarray(1+NewGrayLevels,OldHistogram);
```

This should work so long as your maximum value in NewGrayLevels (+1 because you are starting at zero) is equal to the length of OldHistogram.

Comment: as @Shaun314 suggested, I tried to read the code that developers have written for "histeq" function. Not just for discovering how to eliminate for loop but also for understanding the algorithm used to apply new equalized histogram on the image matrix.I know it's related to the variable map used in edit('histeq') but I didn't understand the algorithm.Do you know anything about this algorithm or can you suggest me away to study this algorithm.(It's a college assignment and I can't use built-in functions)

Comment: See edits for some more ideas on how to vectorize this code. As for applying the transformation, I am not familiar with the exact transformation they are using, but that sounds like it is a part of your college work - what have you been taught? There are plenty of resources online (e.g. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html) to help understand this.

Comment: Dear @Hugh Nolan thanks for your attention.If you want to get familiar with the algorithm used to apply new equalized histogram on the image matrix, see [my next question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303335/apply-new-equalized-histogram-on-the-image-matrix-in-matlab)